# Aligning equations left

Tags: equations, split, subequations

I need to align the equation left. I used the command

```
\begin{fleqn}
\end{fleqn}
```

and

```
 \begin{equation}
\begin{split}
x=yz+q\\ 
y=te+3\\ 
z=uy+4,
```

\end{split}
\end{equation}

but I didn't get the desired form. Can I get any help for this?

Comment: always show a complete test, neither of your fragments can work, the first is an empty evironment the second has  `\begin{split} x=yz+q, y=te+3, z=uy+4,\end{equation}`  you should just need `\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The `\begin{fleqn} \end{fleqn}` code snippet is somewhat meaningless, I'm afraid, as it contains no math material. For the second code snippet to have a chance at compiling correctly, `\end{split}` has to come before, not after, `\end{equation}`. The second code snippet provides no `&` alignment points; hence, all three equations will be right-aliged. If you need them to the left-aligned, place `&` alignment point indicators at the start of each of the 3 rows.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `[fleqn]` option so equations flush left rather than centre.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\section{align}
\begin{align}
x&=yz+q\\ 
y&=te+3\\ 
z&=uy+4
\end{align}

\section{aligned}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
x&=yz+q\\ 
y&=te+3\\ 
z&=uy+4
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```